# R Change ggplot scatterplot colors

Tags: ggplot2

I'm an R newbie and have searched for the answer to this to no avail.

I have a simple ggplot scatterplot that I set the color to "cluster" of which there are 3.  The plot comes out great and is colored in 3 shades of blue.  I want the colors to be dark blue, orange, and green.  How do I do this?  I've been toying with scale_color_manual and cannot get anything to work.

Cheers
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly cluster is a numeric variable, then ggplot uses scale_color_continuous. Try converting "cluster" to character or to factor and then try scale_color_manual

Answer (score 0):

What does your data/code look like? You scale_color_manual should look like this:

```
scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "orange", "green")
```